# Delete Android package uninstallation

Tags: android

My goal is to delete the uninstallation thing from the system that we press and hold on android phones and uninstall applications.

but I couldn't find the name of the package because I want to remove it.
Thank you.

I looked at system apps in settings but couldn't find a solution

Comment: So you want to uninstall the uninstaller? To my knowledge there is no such component you could uninstall. App installations and reinstallations are handled by the package manager service but thet is a core system part that can not be changed. I get the feeling you should better ask what you actually want to achieve.